# tikz: connecting to a rectangle split shape

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a simple diagram using `tikz` to show the structure of a compiler front end.

The compiler is being represented with a node using rectangle split shape containing three parts. The input and output are being represented by rectangles node and should connect to the left of the first and to the right of the last parts of the split shape, respectively.

I have written the document below, but it is not working.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, data/.style={rectangle,fill=red!12}]
  \node[rectangle split,rectangle split parts=3,draw,anchor=center] (compiler) {
    lexical analysis\nodepart{two}
    syntatic analysis\nodepart{three}
    semantic analysis
  };

  \node[data] (src) [left=of compiler.text,align=center] {source code};
  \node[data] (obj) [right=of compiler.three,align=center] {intermediate code};

  \draw [->] (src.east) -- (compiler.text west);
  \draw [->] (compiler.three east) -- (obj.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: compiler front end]

How should it be modified to work as expected?

Comment: Does saying `\node[data] (obj) [right=of compiler.three east,align=center] {intermediate code};` do what you want?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes. And how to force the arrow from "source code" to be horizontal?

Comment: Use the `-|` syntax, such as `\draw [->] (src.east) -- (src.east-|compiler.text west);`

Comment: Same thing, see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply changing from `left=of compiler.text` and `right=of compiler.three` to `left=of compiler.text west` and `right=of compiler.three east`  for the `src` and `obj` nodes improves the output.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, data/.style={rectangle,fill=red!12}]
  \node[rectangle split,rectangle split parts=3,draw,anchor=center] (compiler) {
    lexical analysis\nodepart{two}
    syntatic analysis\nodepart{three}
    semantic analysis
  };

  \node[data] (src) [left=of compiler.text west,align=center] {source code};
  \node[data] (obj) [right=of compiler.three east,align=center] {intermediate code};

  \draw [->] (src.east) -- (compiler.text west);
  \draw [->] (compiler.three east) -- (obj.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any command like `circle split` and `circle split parts=3`?

Comment: @HarishKumar There is a `circle split` shape, but it has as far as I can see only two parts, `text` and? `lower`. See the section *Shapes with Multiple Text Parts* in the *Shape Library* chapter of the PGF manual. (In my CVS version it is chapter 53.6 on page 497.)