# How can i draw this graph in latex? is it possible?

Tags: tables

[image: have to draw this table in latex, but i can not, help me]

I try to but, i dd not, if it is possible please help me to draw

Comment: Have you made any attempt yet? If so please post the code you have so far.

Comment: I try to find some similiar examples but i did not find, the only thing i can do is a create a basis tale? what do you think it is possible to draw in latex?

Comment: Welcome to SE. Of course this is possible. For example with `pstrick` or with `tikz` or ...  so, consider comment of @Null.

Comment: can you add these code in here?

Comment: I have no idea how to begin this kind of table. I am a beginner. So I am hoping to find some help around here. Please help

Comment: Must it really be rotated?

Comment: No, it must not.

Comment: normally, be flat

Comment: Can you just scan this image and put it in your document? Draw it in Powerpoint, save it as a pdf and put it in your document?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
\documentclass[tikz,
               border=1mm,
               preview]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

    \begin{document}
        \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=0pt,
    ML/.style = {font=\small\sffamily, text height=1.75ex, inner sep=2pt}
                    ]
\matrix (M)  [matrix of math nodes,
              column sep=-.4pt, row sep=-0.4pt,
              nodes={draw, thin, inner sep=2mm, 
                     text height=2.5ex, text depth=1ex, text width=3em,
                     align=center}]
{
\mathsf{H_2} &   \mathsf{H_3} &   \mathsf{H_4}         \\
\mathsf{H_1} &   \mathsf{S}   &   \mathsf{H_3}         \\
\mathsf{T}   &   \mathsf{H_1} &   \mathsf{H_2}         \\
};
\node[ML,left=of M-1-1] {$\vdots\vdots$};
\node[ML,left=of M-1-1.south west] {1};
\node[ML,left=of M-2-1.south west] {e};
\node[ML,below left=of M-3-1.south west] {0};
%
\node[ML,below=of M-3-1.south east] {e};
\node[ML,below=of M-3-2.south east] {1};
\node[ML,below=of M-3-3] {$\vdots\vdots$};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Above code gives:

[image]

For drawing of your picture/graph I select TikZ package since I'm quite familiar with it. Graph is based on `matrix` library, by which I define matrix of math nodes. Nodes style is determined in `\matrix` option.

This MWE should serve to you for further investigation of capability of the TikZ package and refinement according to your taste.

Manual of the TikZ is huge, however for start read its part III (TikZ ist kein Zeichenprogramm)  and than description of `matrix` library.

Answer (score 0):

The small numbers written in front of the edges makes this something complicated. One solution is to use `TikZ` package as described here: [TikZ: how to draw chained tabular material](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59286/99176)

Another solution is drawing the table in Inkscape and export as a graphic compatible with LaTeX.

Comment: I am not good at do it. I hope that if it is possible, may be i can codes for this table..

Comment: If you are not good in coding it, the best choice is drawing it by some software, e.g. Inkscape. So, you can import it as a PDF file into your LaTeX file to compile by `pdflatex` .